# Does hugging Leonardo da Vinci yield any benefits?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I just recently arrived in Venice in Assassin's Creed 2 (PC version) and started the first mission where a man gives me and Leonardo da Vinci a quick tour of Venice. At the end, there is a cut-scene with a quick-time event. Leonardo da Vinci initiates a hug and the game prompts you to push a button. Seeing as it was a cutscene, I sat back not expecting this and watched until it was too late to hug him. Leonardo makes a sad face and walks away which made me feel like a jerk.

Does hugging or not hugging Leonardo da Vinci provide any benefits or penalties later in the game? Would it be worth replaying the mission (and how) for the other outcome? Can I save my bromance?

Comment: "Is that a paintbrush, or are you ... oh, it is?  Oh."

Comment: It's arguably a benefit to not hug Leonardo, because of the hilariously awkward denial.

Comment: I missed this part to and was nearly tempted to restatrt the whole thing just to see what happened. Does anyone have or know of a video of this cutscene where Leonardo gets his hug? I have a huge OCD about this kind of thing, so please help :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I, too, missed this moment<sup>1</sup> and was a little bit annoyed, he gives you such a hurt look afterwards too...

Anyway, at the time, I investigated and it seems that **this has no effect on the game outside this cutscene**. This is apparently also the same for the other quick time events in the game.

Good job too really, since there's a only a few events in the entire game and they all catch you unaware; if they were made important it'd be simply cause too many problems for players.

<sub><sup>1</sup>PC control issues, rant rant rant</sub>